# Sprite kit detect sound completion

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

I have used sequence of action and one of the action plays sound for me.

```
        SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1];

        NSString* completion_sound = self.gameData[@"level_data"][@"completion_sound"];
        SKAction *playSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:completion_sound waitForCompletion:NO];

        SKAction *completion = [SKAction runBlock:^{

            // do some code here.

        }];

        SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, playSound, completion]];

        [self runAction:sequence];
```

But I want to detect a completion of sound. seems like sound is still playing while block is invoking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are passing **NO** for the `waitForCompletion:` argument and it should be **YES**.

> If YES, the duration of this action is the same as the length of the audio playback. If NO, the action is considered to have completed immediately.

So change to YES in this line of code...

```
SKAction *playSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:completion_sound waitForCompletion:YES];
```

...and the `playSound` action duration will be the length of the sound, therefor the 'completion block' `SKAction *completion` will not be executed until the sound is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence is wrong. The correct order should be:

```
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[playSound, wait, completion]];
```

Comment: wait it's another action as well I want at start, I think Bamsworld asnswer is correct, but thanks for answer